# Ruby: How to replace odd/even occurrences in a string

Tags: ruby

```
input = AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
```

How do I

- Replace odd (1st, 3rd, 5th) occurrence with `:`
- Replace even (2nd, 4th) occurrence with `.`

Comment: Occurrence of what? The `-`?

Answer (score 5):

```
input.gsub("-").with_index(1){|_, i| i.odd? ? ":" : "."}
# => "AA:AA.AA:AA.AA:AA"
```

Comment: cool, I didn't know about with_index

Comment: `with_index` starts at 0 by default.  You can set the initial value to one.  It gets rid of the magical `i+1` expression. `input.gsub("-").with_index(1){|_,i| i.odd? ? ":" : "."}`

Comment: Shorter: `input.gsub("-").with_index {|_, i| ':.'[i % 2]}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, although its not the one-liner you're probably looking for:

```
input = 'AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA'
input.count('-').times do |i|
  replacement = i.even? ? ':' : '.'
  input.sub!('-', replacement)
end
input
# => "AA:AA.AA:AA.AA:AA"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = "AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA".gsub("AA-AA", ":-.")
```

perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
count= 0
input.gsub!(/\-/) do |s|
  count+= 1; s= count% 2== 0 ? '.' : ':'
end
```