# How to replace character at even position by ( and odd position by )

Tags: regex, replace, str-replace

Is it possible to write down a regular expression such that the first $ sign will be replaced by a (, the second with a ), the third with a (, etc ?

For instance, the string

```
This is an $example$ of what I want, $ 1+1=2 $ and $ 2+2=4$.
```

should become

```
This is an (example) of what I want, ( 1+1=2 ) and ( 2+2=4).
```

Comment: No. Regex is for finding patterns (one or multiple with the global flag), not the nth occurrence of one character. You would have to specify the surrounding to apply a useful regex here (e.g. every `$` directly before/after a number). You're better of just using an index function to find all indices where a certain character is.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of an indirect solution, but in some languages, you can use a [callback function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for the replacement. You can then cycle through the options in that function. This would also work with more than two options. For example, in Python:

```
>>> text = "This is an $example$ of what I want, $ 1+1=2 $ and $ 2+2=4$."
>>> options = itertools.cycle(["(", ")"])
>>> re.sub(r"\$", lambda m: next(options), text)
'This is an (example) of what I want, ( 1+1=2 ) and ( 2+2=4).'
```

Or, if those always appear in pairs, as it seems to be the case in your example, you could match both `$` and everything in between, and then replace the `$` and reuse the stuff in between using a group reference `\1`; but again, not all languages support those:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\$(.*?)\$", r"(\1)", text)
'This is an (example) of what I want, ( 1+1=2 ) and ( 2+2=4).'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to an answer already posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13947249/6332575 in Ruby you can use

yourstring.gsub("$").with_index(1){|_, i| i.odd? ? "(" : ")"}

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can use str_replace, which only replaces the first match, and a while loop to deal with pairs of matches at a time.

```
# For str_*
library(stringr)
# For the pipes
library(magrittr)

str <- "asdfasdf $asdfa$ asdfasdf $asdf$ adsfasdf$asdf$"

while(any(str_detect(str, "\\$"))) {
   str <- str %>%
     str_replace("\\$", "(") %>%
     str_replace("\\$", ")")
}
```

It's not the most efficient solution, probably, but it will go through and replace $ with ( and ) through the whole string.

Comment: What language is this? I assume `str_replace` here will only replace the first instance it finds? You might want to add that information.

Comment: Sorry, thought this was tagged with R. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
function replace$(str) {
  let first = false;
  return str.replace(/\$/, _ => (first = !first) ? '(' : ')');
}
```